# Why exponential function giving different results in java and python?

Tags: java, python

I came around a very strange issue when trying to find the 2^64 in java and in python.
In java, 2^64 is producing output `18446744073709552000.000000` ~  while in python its producing `18446744073709551616`.

And the correct answer is the one that is produced by python script. i.e. `18446744073709551616`

Can someone help me to understand this weird behaviour?

Python:

```
print(pow(2,64)); //18446744073709551616
```

Java:

```
System.out.printf("%f",Math.pow(2,64)); //8446744073709552000.000000
```

Comment: [`Math.pow`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html#pow(double,double)) in Java uses double, which means it is a floating point. If you need to be exact look at `BigInteger` instead.

Comment: in addition to @MarkRotteveel's comment: floating points become very imprecise the higher the value.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Thanks for pointing out the Double return by Math.pow(). I've used this BigInteger and BigDecimal before but not aware of broken floating point calcuations in java.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel +2

Comment: Be aware, in Java, float is a different type than double (float is 32 bit floating point, double is 64 bit floating point). And there is nothing "broken" about floating point calculations, and this is not specific to Java: it happens for all calculations with floating point numbers in all languages.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Just corrected my comment regarding Float and Double. Thanks again for clear this out that it's not related to programming languages. Just checked in Google's BigQuery its POW(2,64) is producing the same output as java i.e. `8446744073709552000`